# Using Animation subclasses inflated from XML

Tags: android, xml, animation, subclassing

I have successfully inflated `View` subclasses from XML using custom attributes I've added, but `View` hierarchies in layouts are such that you can specify an item's fully qualified class name in the XML.  Animation elements, on the other hand, just use `<set>`, `<alpha>` and so on.  Is there a way to make a subclass of `AlphaAnimation` and then inflate that from XML like a regular `AlphaAnimation`?